# Saving divs and use them in other html files?

Tags: java, css, html

I would like to save my divs, perhaps in a file and use them later in other html files, so to save me editing the files over and over again.

Comment: Search for template engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have many options (3 possible below - basically its templating):

1) use jquery to load the file and insert the content OR use something like handlebars.js (which is a javascript templating and databinding lib)

2) use a server side language (such as java) to open, read and concatenate the div where you need

3) use a custom desktop application to concatenate them and output a single file

loads of ways to skin this cat.